# pyPeg2 recursive grammar rules

Tags: python, parsing, grammar

I'm trying to make a propositional logic parser, that can take in an input like 'and(P(),not P())' and and convert it to `And(Predicate(P),Negation(Predicate(P)))`. I'm doing this in python, using the pyPEG2 library. Here's what my code looks like:

```
class Formula(List):
    pass

# Predicate class
class Predicate:
    grammar = attr('name', predicate_name_regex) , "(" , attr('terms', csl(Formula)) , ")"

# Variable class
class Variable:
    grammar = attr('name', function_name_regex)

# And class
class AndFormula:
    grammar = K("and(") , attr('left', Formula) , "," , attr('right', Formula) , ")"

# similar prop. logic connectives and terms... etc

# Formula class

class Formula(List):
    grammar = [AndFormula,Predicate,Variable] #plus all the other grammars...


# Parsing function
def parse_formula(input_text):
    return parse(input_text, Formula)

# Example usage:
input_text = "and(a,b)"
parsed_formula = parse_formula(input_text)
print(input_text)
print(f'{parsed_formula}:{parsed_formula.__dict__}')
```

Now the error I'm getting is a `SyntaxError: expecting Keyword('and(')`, which as far as I can tell, just means that the parser isn't able to recognize the keywords in the input text. However, if my input text is just `input_text = 'x'` (just a variable), that works fine. So, it seems that the issue is with the fact that `Predicate` and `AndFormula` have `Formula`'s inside their definition, when `Formula` isn't really defined until later.

Or, I might be completely off the mark about the issue, but either way, any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!